# How to make UITableView height fit its content in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UITableView` and i want the height to fit its content with on extra space as you can see from the images. When i have more than 2 rows, the `tableView` will look fine but for 1 or 2 rows it will have this extra space at the bottom. I would like to mention that i do want to fix the height of my `tableView`. 4 rows is my max.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: no it is not I put the green so it easy it see the different , I will add another image

Comment: Try set table view background color to clear

Comment: please explain more!! you want height of cell to be fit or height of tableView ?

Comment: you were correct setting the background color to clear fix the issue

Comment: @Nouf I created answer from my comment. You can confirm.

Answer (score 1):

What you think that is row with wrong height is actually just your table view background.

If you change your table view background color to clear it should fix your issue.

You can use:

**Code**

```
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

Comment: It was the background color I did set it default, but I did not notice that the red line that make clear was missing so the background was white and not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning scrolling off

`isScrollingEnabled = false`

and use it's `intrinsicContentSize` with autolayout or just it's `contentSize` to resize the tableView to exactly fit it's content and get updated automatically.